CSS cut transparent box in parent background
I have a wrapper that has a header, content and footer.
The body is an image, and the wrapper is also an image. The header and footer background are transparent, making the wrapper background image visible. Still, I need to somehow cut the wrapper background in the content div, so the body background image is visible.
I tried it with box-shadow and other hacks but they won't work since the body and wrapper backgrounds are both images.


body {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1713813091291-ba9b947b8803?q=80&w=1926&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D");
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1712668405876-d0df5c444e62?q=80&w=1932&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D");
  background-size: cover;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.header {
  height: 10rem;
  border-bottom: solid 2px black;
}

.footer {
  height: 5rem;
  border-top: solid 2px black;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Content
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>



I also tried a workaround to toggle the wrapper background image off and add background images to the header and footer separately but then the images were misaligned.
Since the content background image is togglable. I use content something like tabs so sometimes the background should be transparent and sometimes it should be the wrapper background image.
To clarify body is not an actual image but rather transparent since it is all in CEF so when the body is transparent the game is shown.
example image

Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Here you go codepen link

@CroatiaGM As Paulie_D noted, your code example must be in the question itself, not a link to another site

No sure if this is exactly what you are looking for. But you need to change the location of the images. (I have changed heights to px here in the snippet. You can change it back to rem.)
https://codepen.io/ndyhobtc-the-sans/pen/PoggYEQ


body {
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-image:   url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1713813091291-ba9b947b8803?q=80&w=1926&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D");
  background-size: cover;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1712668405876-d0df5c444e62?q=80&w=1932&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D");
  background-position: center;
}

.header {
  height: 20%;
  border-bottom: solid 2px black;
}

.footer {
  height: 20%;
  border-top: solid 2px black;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Content
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>




Hi, the problem is I don't have access to the image, since it's not an image body is set to transparent and everything is in CEF meaning that the game render is behind it, that why I am looking for a way to cut the background image, I can't get part of that game render to just display it as an image in the content.

I represented the game render as an image in-example since that is the closest thing to it, to be able to reproduce it. So when cutting wrappers background image and body image should be visible in the content div. I am looking for something like a mask.
